# If Else statement with Image in vb

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, xaml

I want when I click the first image (powerOn) it goes to run connection() function and change it to second image (powerOff), and vice versa. With my code below, when I click the Image it can run connection () function, but the image is disappear and doesn't change to second image. How to solve that?

```
Private powerOn As ImageSource = New BitmapImage(New Uri("Resources/power_on.png", UriKind.Relative))
Private powerOff As ImageSource = New BitmapImage(New Uri("Resources/power_off.png", UriKind.Relative))

Private Sub connection()
    intDisconnected = False
    If lb_con.Source is powerOn Then
        If (CheckInternetConnection() = True) Then
            Try
                'Some code here
                lb_con.Source = powerOff
            Catch exc As Exception
                MsgBox(exc.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Connection Error")
            End Try    
        Else
            MsgBox(exc.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Connection Error")
        End If
    ElseIf lb_con.Source is powerOff Then
        intDisconnected = True
        If
            'some code here
        End if
        conup = False
        lb_con.Source = powerOn
    End If
    lb_con.focus()
End Sub

Private Sub lb_con_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles lb_con.MouseDown
    If e.LeftButton = MouseButtonState.Pressed Then
        connection()
    End If
End Sub
```

Do you know what's wrong with my code? Thank you in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: You need to debug your code properly, setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code line by line to see what it actually does and where and how that differs from your expectations.

Comment: I see number of problems in that code. For one thing, lb_con.Source = powerOff is wrapped in an exception handler yet the message box would report it as a "Connection Error". Any error there would be caused trying to change the image. It has nothing to do with the connection. If I were you, I'd start looking at what was actually happening there.

Comment: The lb_con.Source = powerOff is not in the exception.

Comment: From the code you provided, we can't locate the problem.
You should do step-by-step debugging to see if the code runs step by step as you think.

Comment: like i said earlier, you need to notify xaml that property has changed. Look into notifypropertychanged class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged?view=net-7.0